# format particular cell value based on a condition in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkRvj.jpg

Above link is the image of the table !!!

```
$grid->setColProperty('KBID', array("width"=>50,"formatter"=>"js:formatKbid"));
$custom0 = <<<CUSTOM0
function formatKbid(cellValue, options, rowData) {
return "<a href='detail.php' style='text-decoration:none;'>
"+cellValue+" </a><a href='www.google.com'><img src=\"../images/task.gif 
\"/></a>";}
CUSTOM0;
$grid->setJSCode($custom0);
```

Actually the problem is, I attached a gif to each entries of one column in the jqGrid but my requirement is I want to attach gif only to the few entries in the jqgrid not to all based on some condition. Which function of jqgrid should i use to format particular entry inside the jqgrid ?

Comment: you should just test the properties of `rowData` for the condition which you need and add the `<img>` based on the condition.

Comment: Can you give me an example of it...?

Comment: I don't use commercial version of jqGrid myself. The format of `rowData` depend on `datatype` and the format of input data for jqGrid which you use.